# How to limit the map bounds in RMMapView and zoom level

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I need to limit zoom and map bounds in `RMMapView` but I want to do it separately.

So I know method `setConstraintsSouthWest:northEast:` but it changes the zoom level to. How to prevent of changing the zoom limits while I using this method?

Or I need to set zoom limits after I use this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use that method, just set the min and max zoom on the map view itself after setting up the tile sources in order to limit the available zooms to the user.